# Leaflet bind popup + filter

Tags: leaflet, popup, filter

I have problems with the code, I do not know where to place the part with the popup. This does not work if I want to use the data attribute in the popup window:

```
var okruh1= L.geoJSON(trate, {
    color: "#3399FF",
    weight: 5 ,
    filter: function(feature, layer) {   
         return (feature.properties.OBJECTID == "1" );
    },
});  

okruh1.bindPopup(layer.properties.OBJECTID);
```

Comment: There is a comma too much after the `filter` option.

Comment: Also I think that `color` and `weight` need to be defined in the [`style`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#geojson-style) option's function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to the layer in [`bindPopup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#geojson-bindpopup), you need to pass a function, e.g.

```
okruh1.bindPopup(function(layer) { 
    return layer.feature.properties.OBJECTID //returns property of the feature rather than the layer
} );
```